# What is this vocal ornament called?

Tags: technique, voice, terminology, ornaments

There is a vocal technique used in [this audio clip](https://youtu.be/csifZMjwbvU?si=Agr3ourVBWVoBy4u) that sounds Arabic and melismatic on the lyric “smile”. The notes go up from G3 to G#3 and back to G3 again. Some say it is a mordent but I think the tempo is too slow for a mordent. Is there a proper vocal term for this technique?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean, but if you mean the wobble at the end that is naught be regular vibrato.

Comment: I don't hear a trill.  Can you post a longer excerpt for context?

Comment: Basically the wobble at the end has few notes sung on the syllable ,they  are G3 ,G#3, G3 ,it goes up once and returns to the natural note so I had no choice but to call it a trill or mordent .Sorry if that confused you.  If it had multiple notes it would’ve been a melisma but since it only has 2 notes I am not sure what to call it.

Comment: @Sana As already said it is simply a regular form of vibrato.

Comment: This singer often uses quavery vibratos but I’m not talking about that,  it’s the notes that go up and down  on the lyric “smile”. You’re saying that’s also a vibrato?

Comment: In contrast, that series of notes on the word "smile" is sung so slowly that **I hesitate to call it an ornament**.